# Porting DevC++ to Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, dev-c++

I wanted to use DevC++ on Linux, so I've started it with Wine and everything is OK until it came to run the file.

The C file compiles well and a .exe files generated that is able to run on Linux (without Wine)

```
$ file '/media/F6AC746BAC74286F/Dev-Cpp/work/hello_on_nix.exe' 
/media/F6AC746BAC74286F/Dev-Cpp/work/hello_on_nix.exe: PE32 executable for MS Windows (console) Intel 80386 32-bit
$ '/media/F6AC746BAC74286F/Dev-Cpp/work/hello_on_nix.exe' 
Hello World!
```

But the problem is when I come to run this file from inside the IDE, it shows a very small window that doesn't show any thing and if I close it, I get the entire IDE to get closed.

Comment: Are you serious? You want to take the worst, buggiest IDE, one which hasn't been maintained for years, and *use it on more platforms*?
Why would you inflict so much pain on yourself? Leave this pile of junk to die its long overdue death and use a real IDE and an up-to-date compiler

Answer (score 0):

Have you run wine from the command line? Are there "FIXME" warnings on the command line?

Comment: Yes, here's the output:

`fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias -120, std (d/m/y): 1/10/2010, dlt (d/m/y): 30/04/2010`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Anjuta](http://www.anjuta.org/) or [Kdevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/)?